# How to prevent creation of object copy on static call from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I'm currently fixing memory issues in a long time project, and I have come across a particularly memory hungry issue. The problem is, that a class holds a very big static data structure, and also a static remoteSubscriber class. We use a TimerTask to periodically register the subscriber at a remote location.

To do this, relevant fields are passed to the timer which creates a complete copy of the class ConnectionManager class. This includes the *massive* data structure.

To prevent having our most data hungry object *twice*, I'd like to find a way to use those fields, in a way that doesn't require the entire parent object to be copied to the new Thread. RMI comes to mind, but is there any other option aswell?

Here's some pseudo code of the problem:

```
public class ConnectionManager{

private static volatile ConnectionManager INSTANCE=new ConnectionManager();
private BigFatStructure bigMama;
private RemoteSubscriber remoteSubscriber;


private ConnectionManager() {

    }

public void initConnection() {
   //initializes fields
}

private static void connect() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new KeepAliveTask(remoteSubscriber),SOMEVALUE,SOMEVALUE);
        try {
            registerSubscriber();
        } catch (DistributionException e) {
        }

    }

public static ConnectionManager getInstance() {

        if(INSTANCE==null){
            synchronized(ConnectionManager.class){
                if(INSTANCE==null){
                INSTANCE=new ConnectionManager();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}

public class KeepAliveTask extends TimerTask {
    private  RemoteSubscriber remoteSubscriber;

public KeepAliveTask(Subscriber remoteSubscriber){
        this.remoteSubscriber=remoteSubscriber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (ConnectionManager.getInstance().getRemoteSubscriber() != null) {
            try {
                try {
            IRemoteService service = MyProvider.getService();
            service.register(remoteSubscriber);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DistributionException(e);
        }
            } catch (DistributionException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to prevent, that the new thread holds a separate copy of ConnectionManager?

Thanks in advance!

edit: changed the code and description to better reflect the updated state

Comment: How does it create a complete copy of the class? That's rather difficult to do.

Comment: Your edit doesn't answer my question. I don't see any copies of anything here, let alone a class. 'Parent of the static method' is meaningless. As far as I can tell this code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @user207421 I've checked the heapdump, and the thread running TimerTask holds a separate copy the whole ConnectionManager object, which should be a singleton.

Comment: That would be a copy of an *object*, not a *class*, and it cannot possibly include duplicates of static members. You haven't addressed my several other points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've resolved the issue. The cause was, that the class "ConnectionManager" existed in 2 packages and somehow a seperate object was being handled by another part of the program. This other object was previously used for another feature, but since it was removed a while back, simply sacking the code that loaded the other ConnectionManager completely fixed the problem.

Comment: The heap dump would have told you that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Singleton Pattern in order to have one unique object.

https://www.javatpoint.com/singleton-design-pattern-in-java

Take a look at Java Design Patterns, they are well-proved solutions for solving a specific problem/task.

https://www.javatpoint.com/design-patterns-in-java

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll probably have to add, that ConnectionManager is already implemented as a singleton. Weirdly though, the TimerTask, which is a seperate thread, holds an exact copy of the instance.

Comment: How did you create an exact copy of the instance? If it is a singleton, no one should be able to create additional instances.

Comment: Why are the `BigFatStructure` and the `RemoteSubscriber` static? Couldn't they be private fields on your singleton `ConnectionManager` (with maybe getters if someone needs to access them)? And how are these two initialized? (Why is anything `static` in `ConnectionManager` if you have a singleton instance anyway that you could use to access these things).

Comment: I have done a few things with the code: I've removed the static modifiers from all fields except constant variables and the instance, I've added indications that this is a singleton class, I'm now passing the relevant objects to the `TimerTask` directly instead of making a static call on `ConnectionManager` and I've made the `Timer` a local variable. Sadly, the problem is still present.

Comment: Can you do me a favour ,  print the hashcodes of the instances of `ConnectionManager` that your threads create, remember you need 1 `ConnectionManager` Object to be created.